# Connecting Tableau to Mendeley

Tags: tableau-api, mendeley

I have been compiling publications associated with a research center into Mendeley, and I would like to generate data visualizations in Tableau using the data in this citation database. Mendeley does not export to Excel, nor does Tableau natively connect to it. Does anyone have a work around for this? Thanks!